# Cómo obtener otro parámetro en vez de la id en una base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente enlace que funciona perfectamente:

> ver-proyecto.php?id=1

Y me gustaría convertirlo en el siguiente:

> ver-proyecto.php?id=titulo-primer-proyecto

He probado a cambiar

```
function dameUnProyecto($id, $con)
 {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE id = $id";

     return mysqli_query($con, $query);
 }
```

por

```
 function dameUnProyecto($id, $con)
 {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE url = $id";

     return mysqli_query($con, $query);
 }
```

Pero así me da el error

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... on line 16

```
for( ; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ); )
```

> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... on line 66

```
 mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Pego también lo siguiente que supongo que tendrá algo que ver pero no lo tengo muy claro.

```
if( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) )
    {$id = $_GET[ 'id' ];}  else 
    { if (isset($_POST[ 'id']))
        {$id = $_POST[ 'id' ]; }
    else{ header("Location: proyectos.php");}
    }

$result = dameUnProyecto($id, $link);
```

Comment: Recuerda que al principio estas pasando a tu `id` un `int` como parámetro a tu sentencia, y ahora es una cadena, prueba con esto `$query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE url = '$id' ";` usando las comillas simples `'$id'`.

Comment: @d.bulten Pues sí, ha funcionado. Pensaba que ya lo había probado pero se ve que no. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... on line 16

*Este error se debe en caso de que la consulta de un error.*

**A tu pequeño error:**

Al principio le estas pasando un `id` numérico como parámetro con lo cual no te lanza error tu sentencia.

```
//Funciona
$query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE id = $id";
```

Ahora con tu *url* como parámetro sería una *cadena*, con lo cual tu sentencia te lanza error, para evitar ese error simplemente debes escapar con las comillas simples tu parámetro `'$id'`.

**Tu código:**

```
//WHERE url = titulo-primer-proyecto.    
$query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE url = $id";
```

**Código actualizado:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE url = '$id'";
```

Por otro lado te dejo un posible ejemplo obteniendo el valor de tu `GET`:

```
<?php 
//Si esta defindo metodo GET.
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    //Url (ejemplo: hola-mundo).
    $id = filter_var($_GET[ 'id' ], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);//Removes all illegal URL characters from a string.
    //Tu $link.    

    $result = dameUnProyecto($id, $link);
}  else {   
    //Redirección.
    header("Location: proyectos.php");  
}
?>
```

> **Nota:** te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)